# Остановить видео после закрытия окна JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый вечер!

Необходимо сделать, чтоб при закрытии окна, останавливалось видео. Я использовал обработчик событий.

```
         secondStage.setOnCloseRequest(event1 -> {
                                      System.out.println("Работате");
                                      Player ps = new Player();
                                      ps.Stop();

                                  });
```

Метод Stop:

```
 public void Stop() {
    mp.stop();
}
```

В итоге окно не закрывается и выдает:

> at sample.Player.Stop(Player.java:83)
>       at sample.Controller$3.lambda$handle$0(Controller.java:171)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>       at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.closing(WindowPeerListener.java:88)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:121)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$423(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:150)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:148)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1266)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyClose(Window.java:1174)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Я так же не могу понять, почему аналогичный метод работает, который вызывается при нажатии на кнопку.

```
    public void stop(ActionEvent event) {
    mp.stop();
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно пытаться закрыть тот плейер что играет, а не создавать новый и просить его остановиться. ))

Comment: Player - это класс, а stop()  метод в котором прописано остановка данного плеера. Проблема заключается в том, что аналогичный метод работает, который останавливает видео при нажатии на копку.

Comment: Я знаю что такое классы в Java. Я уверен, что в вашем случае вы не пытаетесь остановить экземпляр который был запущен. А нужно обращаться именно к нему.

Comment: Если не трудно, можно не много по подробнее. Проблема в том, что плеер и окно написаны в разных класса.

Comment: Ну блин... как я расскажу... В общем нужно в тот класс который будет останавливать как то передать ссылку на тот объект, который нужно останавливать. И с ним работать. Детальнее я никак не смогу уже раскрыть вопрос.)

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Grow прав, но может у меня получиться объяснить проще.)
Когда вы открываете окно с плеером вы создаете новый объект класса примерно так, как я понимаю:

```
Player ps = new Player();
....
```

и когда вы пытаетесь закрыть окно и вызывается setOnCloseRequest вы опять же создаете новый объект класса и и закрываете его, а ваш первноначальный объект остается не тронутым. В методе setOnCloseRequest нужен просто ps.Stop();
если конечно переменная ps определена в этом классе. Вот пример:

```
class A{ 
  private B b = new B("First");
  public void out b(){
    B b = new B("Second");
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

на выводе получим: Second
как-то так